# Vectorize 3D assignment

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorize (do the same without the for loop) this problem?

```
A=[(1:5)' (1:5)' (1:5)'];
B=ones(1000,5);

D=size(A,1)
C=zeros(1000,3,5)

for y=1:D
C(:,:,y)=B(:,A(y,:));
end
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Matlab?

Comment: Matlab. Added the tag right now.

Comment: You can always sacrifice memory and do `repmat`. However I think this is a good approach and will not necessarily be slower than using `repmat`

Comment: The matrix A can have random numbers between 1 and 5. And the matrix B can have completely random numbers.

Comment: Don't vectorize stuff unless it's your program's bottleneck. And always measure before and after. Vectorized code is not necessarily faster than a loop in the latest versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize this easily with a couple of calls to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
C = reshape(B(:, reshape(A.', [], 1)), size(B, 1), [], size(B, 2));
```

This first places each row of `A` sequentially into a row vector (of size 1-by-15), indexes `B` with it (resulting in a 1000-by-15 matrix), then reshapes `B` to a 3-D matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to vectorize this with just a single call to `reshape`:

```
C = reshape((B(:,A')),1000,3,5);
```

Like others have mentioned in the comments, this doesn't actually save you much computation time. When I ran 1000 trials of your original implementation and mine, the loop took 4.8264e-05 seconds while the vectorized version took 3.1495e-05 seconds.

If you were to scale the problem up, and replace `B=ones(1000,5);` with `B=ones(1000000,5);` the execution time is 0.0855 seconds for the loop, 0.0611 seconds for the vectorized version with 2 calls to `reshape`, and 0.0605 seconds with the vectorized version I posted here. The time savings are a bit greater as the problem scales, but again, maybe not a meaningful difference.

edit: the timings listed above are for MATLAB version (R2016a)